# Android CircleCi Execution failed for task ':app:connectedDebugAndroidTest' Error

Tags: android, github, continuous-integration, circleci

I'm trying to figure out Circle CI with Android Programming. I've managed to figure out every error I've come across , except for when ever it starts running Expresso Tests, I get this error:

> : No compatible devices connected.[TestRunner] FAILED 
>   Found 1 connected device(s), 0 of which were compatible.
>   :app:connectedDebugAndroidTest FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':app:connectedDebugAndroidTest'.
>     There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///home/circleci/code/app/build/reports/androidTests/connected/index.html

I've tried researching online and I cannot find anything at all. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `No compatible devices connected`... Well, does CircleCI have a physically attached device?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using circle ci 2.0, here is a success demo https://github.com/gengjiawen/android-circleci-2.0.